# HTML Embedded Email Functionality (re: Parsing)

Tags: html, email, parsing, html-parsing, html-email

I am making an email template that can get responses without linking externally. Using java would get the email marked as spam, so I have been trying to use HTML and CSS.

Is it possible to get/store numerous responses from an HTML embedded email? In the perfect situation, the recipient would fill out the fields, hit submit (still in the email), and their responses would send to my database where I can parse them later.
I was thinking it may be easier to embed a website in the email instead?

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: That'd be something.. being able to just mail a working form to someone. The world of phishing will bow to your feet if you manage that!

Comment: Seriously though: No, you can't. Even if you could, there's still something known as the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Let's hope that day comes sooner than later!

Comment: Any advice on any other ways that you could see it working?

Comment: There isn't. My first response was being sarcastic. If you could do such things, it would be extremely easy for anyone to start phishing ppl. Sure you can use html in an email, but it's very limited and for good reason! You can't use scripts, forms etc. If you require data from the receipent, they'll have to visit your website first.

Comment: And as I've said, even if you could, the Same Origin Policy prevents any type of data being send between 2 different hosts / servers unless both servers are configured to accept data exchange between eachother.